# XML Serialize C#

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm using

```
List<EFacebook> facebooks = BFacebook.ReadFacebookFriends(user.EProviders
    .Where(i => i.ProviderType == EProvider.EnumProviderType.Facebook)
    .First().Token);

StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder();
foreach (EFacebook i in facebooks)
{
   xml.AppendFormat("<id>{0}</id>", i.id);
}
```

Can anybody suggest a better code to serialize each `i.id` into an XML string?

Edit:
The facebook object has close to 20 properties. If I `XmlSerializer` all 20 properties are serialized into the XML. I just need the `id` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [XML Serialization](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813) already built into the .NET Framework.

You can use code similar to the following to serialize the object:

```
MySerializableClass myObject = new MySerializableClass();
// Insert code to set properties and fields of the object.
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new 
XmlSerializer(typeof(MySerializableClass));
// To write to a file, create a StreamWriter object.
StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter("myFileName.xml");
mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, myObject);
myWriter.Close();
```

See: [How to serialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szzyf24s%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

You can flag properties to be ignored using the XmlIgnore attribute as shown below:

```
public class Group
{
   // The XmlSerializer ignores this field.
   [XmlIgnore]
   public string Comment;

   // The XmlSerializer serializes this field.
   public string GroupName;
}
```

See [XMLIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute%28v=VS.80%29.aspx#Y456)

Comment: I tried to use that. But I cant figure out how to serialize only the Id column into a big string instead of serialize the whole object.

Comment: You can use the XmlIgnoreAttribute ignore attribute to mark other properties so they won't be serialized.

Comment: Do you have a sample code to serialize the list into a xml (string)?

Comment: I dont want to serialize it into a file, how can i keep it into a string? StreamReader?

Comment: You don't have to send it to a file. I just copied the code from MSDN. You can serialize to a memory stream then use a StreamReader to dump that back into a String.

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(int[]));
xs.Serialize(stream,facebooks.Select(x=>x.id).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use Linq To Xml to create the Xml Tree structure

See for an example: [Linq To Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387019.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just saving the `id` values into an xml string then I wouldn't say that you're 'serializing' the objects.

Whenever working with XML it's much nicer to use an XML library than to wrangle with text. One obvious reason is that it guarantees your XML will be well-formed.

I'd do something like this:

```
List<EFacebook> facebooks = GetFriends();
var facebookIds = facebooks.Select(f => new XElement("id", f.id));
var facebookXml = new XElement("facebookIds", facebookIds);
```

Which will give you XML like

```
<facebookIds>
  <id>1</id>
  <id>2</id>
</facebookIds>
```